# Dialogflow Messenger -- Selecting Environment

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

How does one select an environment for the Dialogflow Messenger? We have 3 different environments (dev, QA, prod) and want to select Prod for the Dialogflow Messenger we deploy on our site.

There doesn't seem to be any setting where you can select the environment?

Comment: I have a question. Which Dialogflow do you use, ES or CX. The way may differ, so I want to ask.

Comment: We are using Dialogflow CX

Answer (score 0):

In Dialogflow CX, we can select environment before enabling Dialogflow Messenger.
Like the picture below, select the environment in the dropdown when connect Dialogflow Messenger integration so that the it will work with selected environment.

If you already enabled it, then disable it to select environment.

[image]